# Queries using the slingr Javascript API

Tags: javascript, slingr

I'm trying to use the sys.data.createQuery() method that is described in the docs. I have an entity called 'companies' and I'm trying to retrieve all of the companies like this:

```
var companies = sys.data.createQuery('companies');
```

But this isn't working, is there another way of getting all of the records of an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query and the iterate over the results like this:

```
var query = sys.data.createQuery('companies');
// add filters to the query as you want here
var records = sys.data.find(query);
while (records.hasNext()) {
  var record = records.next();
  sys.logs.info(record.label());
}
```